# aws codedeploy long-running process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, long-running-processes

Aws codedeploy is being applied.
The appspec file is shown below.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: script/install-file.sh
    destination: /home/
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: script/install-file.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: script/start-file.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: root
```

I tried Succeeded until AfterInstall.
It is still pending in applicationStart.
AfterInstall installed Java files and set permissions.

```
chmod 755 ${file_HOME}/bin/install_api
chmod 755 ${file_HOME}/bin/install_web
```

Auto-run was set.

```
/bin/cp ${file_HOME}/bin/install_api /etc/init.d
/bin/cp ${file_HOME}/bin/install_web /etc/init.d

Chkconfig --add ib_api
Chkconfig --add ib_web
```

start-file.sh is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
# start InnerBeans
sudo service install_api start &
sleep 5
sudo service install_web start &
sleep 5
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What was the error / result? Can you check the deployment logs to see what codedeploy ran so far? Here's how to find them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html#deployments-view-logs-instance-unix

Answer (score 1):

When calling background processes or daemons inside a LifeCycleEvent script codedeploy-agent (version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1106_rpm) remains pending until 70 minutes timeout.
First, try removing `&` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start InnerBeans
sudo service install_api start
#sleep 5
sudo service install_web start
#sleep 5
```

If it still failing, you probably have background or daemonized processes inside the init script so you need to redirect outputs stdout and stderr.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start InnerBeans
sudo service install_api start > /dev/null 2>&1
#sleep 5
sudo service install_web start > /dev/null 2>&1
#sleep 5
```

That second way worked for me.
I found the solution here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=626766&#626766
and here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-long-running-processes